# How to get event parameters that fired by fireEvent in Extjs

Tags: extjs

How can I get the parameters set in

`fireEvent("event",args);`

When I handle the event, how can I get the `args` in the event handling function. 
Thanks

Comment: check [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments)

Comment: are you firing a custom event or an event already defined by the component you are using?

Answer (score 1):

You should define them as parameters in the function is gonna be handling your event. They are always sent by the event either you define you receive them or not.

Example:

```
Ext.create('Ext.Button', {
    text: 'Click me',
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    handler: function() { // here the function does not receive anything, though a click event on a button does receive parameters
        alert('You clicked the button!');
    }
});
```

This handler of a button's click event doesn't receive the parameters of the click event although they are being sent. The documentation state it:

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.button.Button-event-click

So you could've done :

```
Ext.create('Ext.Button', {
    text: 'Click me',
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    handler: function(button, e, eOpts) { // here you are defining that you would be receiving 3 parameters
        console.log(button.text); // you make sure you are receiving the parameters
        alert('You clicked the button!');
    }
});
```

This of course also applies if you listen the events in a controller.